# Target container in react is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React can't fine container DOM to render JSX. So far no solution to similar questions on Stackoverflow. Most of the answers to such question are for older version of react.

The `script` tag in `index.html` is after the container which means that error is not caused by placing the tag before the container. In one similiar question online, a user said that the issue can be because of webpack configuration. I don't know what to change in the webpack config file.

I'm using react version 6.4.1

#### HTML FILE:

```
<!-- load django static files -->
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Storelead CRM</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.4.1/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-qdQEsAI45WFCO5QwXBelBe1rR9Nwiss4rGEqiszC+9olH1ScrLrMQr1KmDR964uZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">

    <!-- Custom stysheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "frontend/css/sb-admin.css" %}">

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box !important;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
            left: -150% !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="page-top">

    <!-- React -->
    <div id="wrapper" class="app"></div>

     <!-- React script -->
    <script src="{% static "frontend/js/main.js" %}"></script>

    <!-- Boostrap script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
  <script src="{% static "frontend/js/sb-admin.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### REACT FILES:

#### App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import Dashboard from './leads/Dashboard';
import Home from './Home';

import store from '../store'

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="container-fluid">
        <Home/>
      </div>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

#### Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';

const container = document.querySelector('app');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

### Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont use getElementById("wrapper")?

Comment: @Jerome I did that already, but still got the same error.

Comment: and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `document.querySelector('.app')` instead of `document.querySelector('app');`

Comment: @Romeo can you provide error text, and can you put breakpoint after document.querySelector('.app') and make sure that element is exist in runtime? OR just consooe.log(container)?